# Google mobile friendly resources which are blocked by robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have a situation when I check my website on Google Mobile Friendly Test, it says that my website is mobile friendly, but beneath there is a sentence saying: "This page uses 5 resources which are blocked by robots.txt". Three out of these are google maps api links/sources - so I am bit confused about this.

Any links, articles or etc. would help a lot to understand and remove this issue.

And as I am little bit fresh to SEO, how bad this is for my SEO?

Comment: You should not worry about it. Sometime it happens that tool also prefer 3rd party robot.txt where that file access it blocked , For ex: https://ssl.gstatic.com/robots.txt , so in actual it has no concern with your site.

Answer (score 1):

Google needs to know what it serves to its customers. If some content is blocked by `robots.txt`, it cannot analyze it. Therefore, it cannot trust it. Therefore, it often decides to not rank it.

If you can provide access to such content, then do so to stay on the safe side of SEO.